# How can you tell if onedrive for business onedrive-sdk-python is authenticated?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, onedrive

I'm a pastor, and every week I email (through gmail) a link to a powerpoint and the bulletin and a few other items on OneDrive to a couple people in the church. I would prefer to automate the link generation and email sending with Python.

The trouble is, when I run the code provided by Microsoft to give Python access to my OneDrive, I have no idea whether my app is authenticated or not, or how to use the fact that I'm authenticated, if in fact I am.

I copied the code from the OneDrive for Business section of Microsoft's github project onedrive-sdk-python (I am using OneDrive for Business - my onedrive login ends with @onmicrosoft.com) and ran the script. It spun up a browser tab that went to "http://localhost:8080/?code=AQABAAIA"... etc.

The output was "127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2019 11:42:14] "GET /?code=" followed by a very long string of characters.

I commented out the last few lines in the code below because I'm not even sure how this is supposed to work or if I'm supposed to use them; I don't know how many services I have access to or what that even means.

```
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_id = '[my actual client id went here]'
client_secret = '[my client secret]'
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)

# If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
# which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
#service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
#auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
#client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)
```

I expected to be told what to do next, but the readme just has one-line examples. Do I keep the authentication part of the code forever? Do I need to put that long "code=" string somewhere? Was I supposed to be told to sign in? Am I authenticated?